# First-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation $f'(t)=\frac{1+t}{2t^2+f^2(t)}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I don't know how to solve this Cauchy problem,
\begin{cases} f'(t)=\frac{1+t}{2t^2+f^2(t)} \\ f(0)=1 \end{cases}
I tried by applying all theorems and definitions I know, I tried to consider that if I can show that it is limited then the solution exists on all $\mathbb{R}$, but I don't know how to show that. Then I thought that if the derivative is limited, I can prove the local existence... Can anyone help me? Thank you very much

Comment: Do you want an explicit solution or show that there is a unique global solution?

Comment: I would like to state if the solution exists and it is unique

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: Can you take a look at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1506108/laplace-equation-with-tangential-derivative-prescribed-on-the-boundary) too. Many Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$
F(t,f)=\frac{1+t}{2\,t^2+f^2}.
$$
$F$ is continuous and has a continuous partial derivative with respect to $f$ on $D=\{(t,f):f>0\}$. Since $(0,1)\in D$, there is a unique solution defined on a maximal interval $(a,b)$. It is not difficult to see that in fact the solution is defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$. Let's do it for $[0,\infty)$. Since the RHS is positive, $f'>0$ and the solution is increasing. Then $f(t)\ge1$ and
$$
0\le f'(t)\le\frac{1+t}{2\,t^2+1}<\frac{t}{t^2+1}.
$$
It follows that
$$
f(t)=1+\int_0^tf'(s)\,ds\le1+\int_0^t\frac{s}{s^2+1}\,ds=1+\frac12\log(t^2+1).
$$
This implies that the solution is bounded on any bounded interval, and hence can be extended to $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: in this case, is the solution extendable?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: ok, so it is extendable to $[0,+\infty)$ also?

Comment: $[0,\infty)\subset(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: you're very kind, but I'm stuck calculating the solution, how can I calculate it?

Comment: Then why your answer to my comment? It seems that an explicit solution is hard to come by.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand when you say "It is not difficult to see that in fact the solution is defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$", I mean, how can I calculate the solution? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You do not need to solve the equation to prove that the solution is global.

Comment: Thank you very much, last question. If I had $F(t,f)=\frac{3t}{2t^2+f^2}$, would it be correct to write $$0\leq f'(t)\leq \frac{3t}{2t^2+1} \le \frac{3t}{t^2+1}$$ $$f(t)=\int_0^t f'(s)ds \leq \int_0^t \frac{3s}{s^2+1} ds$$? Thank you.

Comment: You should add $f(0)$ to the integrals.

Comment: Where? thank you.

Comment: $f(t)=f(0)+\int_0^tf'(s)\,ds$.